# How to keep a specific folder and delete rest of the files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying delete all files within a folder but there is 1 folder called pictures which I would like to keep but don't know how to do that. I am using the following script , it deletes everything in a folder

```
 if ($message -eq 'y')
 {
 get-childitem "C:\test" -recurse | % { 
remove-item $_.FullName -recurse
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\test" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -cnotmatch "\\Pictures($|\\)" -and (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Include "Pictures" -Recurse).Length -eq 0 } | Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
```

I suspect there must be a way more elegant way to do this. Here's what this does: it enumerates all files in the *C:\test* folder recursively (`Get-ChildItem`), then it removes all items from the result list using `Where-Object` where the path contains the directory to be excluded (specified using regex syntax) or when the item in question has child items that contains the file or directory to be excluded. The resulting list is fed to `Remove-Item` for removal. The `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` switch is applied to prevent errors being logged with recursive removal.

Comment: i am getting the following error A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument '-'   the error is on [Remove-Item]

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. But that's not the only issue with my answer -- as we're doing recursion here, it may also delete Pictures if deep in the directory structure. For instance, C:\test\Pictures will not be deleted, but C:\test\another\Pictures will be deleted when "another" gets deleted. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I have structure like C:\user\transactions\test_trans\tab   inside tab there are files and picture folder, so i would like to keep all the folder structure just want to delete what ever is inside the tab apart from pictures folder

Comment: any idea how to do that

Comment: I'm trying -- no luck so far. If I don't find a solution in the next 30 mins, I'll revoke/delete my answer.

Comment: @user3770612: I have edited my response with a solution that works recursively. I'll be the first to admit that it's clumsy and slow, so if I were you I would seek out the opinion of others as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Force| Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "Pictures"} | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

I just tried this, and it worked for me. If you want to change what is deleted just change the "Pictures". This uses $PSScriptRoot for the path, which is the execution path of the Powershell script. You can rename that to be the path of where you want to delete.

Comment: From what I gather, the OP wants to run this in arbitrary directory depth. If the directory structure is like \dir1\dir2\Pictures, then "dir2" will be deleted, even though it contains a directory called "Pictures".

Comment: This will remove everything not in the first directory named "Pictures".

/root/Pictures - Will still be there.
/root/Folder/Pictures - Will not be.

Comment: That's correct. I was thinking the OP wants to delete everything but Pictures in arbitrary folder depth (see _"I have a structure..."_ comment), but I may be mistaken. Good thing I'm not to decide :)